# Pass function as argument and inject another argument

Tags: clojure

I am trying to write a container function that takes a function name, it's arguments, and calls the function with an additional argument.

I am pretty sure I am doing this wrong, but here's what I've got so far.

```
    (defn get-dyn [& args]
      ((first args) "some" (rest args)))
```

So, the first argument is the function name, and that function can have any number of arguments so I guess I have to accept optional parameter? 
I need to inject a common argument `"some"` into all the functions I call via this function.

so,

```
(get-dyn str 3 4)
(get-dyn str 32 "willhelm")
```

etc.. and I would expect it to be equivalent of doing

```
(str "some" 3 4)
(str "some" 32 "wilhelm")
```

Except, the `(rest args)` returns a set so it doesn't work that way.

I tried doing it with `partial` but couldn't work it out.

Is there a way I can solve this problem? or am I better of using induvidual functions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use apply.

```
user> (defn get-dyn [f & args]
        (apply f "some" args))
#'user/get-dyn
user> (get-dyn str 1 2)
"some12"
user> (get-dyn str " " 1 " " 2)
"some 1 2"
```